# How to set relation for inner array object in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have data in a table like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d1b70b826170df4365489"),
    "userId" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa",
    "mediaId" : "5a99330af218d30c981cda2f",
    "comment" : "Hi this is a video",
    "**replies**" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 1",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa"
        }, 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 2",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa"
        }, 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 3",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : "",
    "updatedAt" : ""
}
```

**My question:**
How to set a relation and include data from **User table** for userId in every object of replies array in loopback?

**My expected Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d1b70b826170df4365489"),
    "userId" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa",
    "mediaId" : "5a99330af218d30c981cda2f",
    "comment" : "Hi this is a video",
    "**replies**" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 1",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa",
            "userDetails":{
               "name":"xxxxxxxxx",
               "address":"xxxxxxxx"
            }

        }, 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 2",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa",
            "userDetails":{
               "name":"xxxxxxxxx",
               "address":"xxxxxxxx"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "comment" : "this is a reply 3",
            "**userId**" : "5a93e0b76d32cd0e6c1b99aa",
            "userDetails":{
               "name":"xxxxxxxxx",
               "address":"xxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : "",
    "updatedAt" : ""
}
```

I am getting stuck up here.Kindly share some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

1. create 3 models: yourModel, user, reply
2. set these [relations](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-model-relations.html) in [model definition json](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html) or using node api:

> yourModel **embedsMany** Replies, Reply **belongsTo** user, user
>   **hasMany** Replies

3. query data using a stringified json as include filter

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html#using-stringified-json-in-rest-queries

> {include: {relatedModel1: [{relatedModel2: 'relationName'} , 'relatedModel']}}

something like this maybe

```
/api/your_model/?filter={"include":{"replies":{"userDetails":true}}}
```